# how to POST parameters to server using retrofit2?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

i want to POST data from android to server side using retrofit2 like :
https://192.168.1.1/image?iname=VAR
and VAR is variable from the user

```
interface ModelApi {
    @POST("/image")
    suspend fun pushImageToModelFromAPI(
        @Body file: RequestBody,
    )
}
```

i tried the above code but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For query params you need to use @Query. Like this:

```
interface ModelApi {
    @POST("/image")
    suspend fun pushImageToModelFromAPI(
        @Body file: RequestBody,
        @Query("iname") name: String
    )
}
```